# Symfony 5, Doctrine - Best Practice for Inserting a "Miscellaneous" Script

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

**The Problem**: I'm looking to implement the DateTime script found in the Doctrine 2.7 docs [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html#working-with-datetime-instances). I'm having trouble figuring out where this script should naturally go in Symfony 5's file structure.

**The Setup**: Used Composer to create a Symfony 5 website skeleton using `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton`.

**The Context**: I don't have any real code implemented yet as I'm still trying to learn how Symfony works with Doctrine. I'm trying to do everything right with Symfony, including figuring out where files should go. From what I understand, each php script found in `src` is either a *Controller*, an *Entity*, or a *Repository*. I don't see where to reasonably put the DateTime script without making another folder.

Any guidance is much appreciated! Thank you.

EDIT: The specific script I'm referring to is this class definition of UTCDateTimeType. I was under the impression that a skeleton was made to be THE file structure you worked with to allow for easy maintainability.

```
<?php

namespace DoctrineExtensions\DBAL\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType;

class UTCDateTimeType extends DateTimeType
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTimeZone
     */
    private static $utc;

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($value instanceof \DateTime) {
            $value->setTimezone(self::getUtc());
        }

        return parent::convertToDatabaseValue($value, $platform);
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if (null === $value || $value instanceof \DateTime) {
            return $value;
        }

        $converted = \DateTime::createFromFormat(
            $platform->getDateTimeFormatString(),
            $value,
            self::getUtc()
        );

        if (! $converted) {
            throw ConversionException::conversionFailedFormat(
                $value,
                $this->getName(),
                $platform->getDateTimeFormatString()
            );
        }

        return $converted;
    }
    
    private static function getUtc(): \DateTimeZone
    {
        return self::$utc ?: self::$utc = new \DateTimeZone('UTC');
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just a skeleton. Files can have other purposes. You're free to make your own additional folders to cover those purposes.

Comment: which DateTime script, could you please be more specific?

Comment: I was looking at the first script under the header "Handling different Timezones with the DateTime Type" which defines the class UTCDateTimeType. I haven't worked with many frameworks before so I wasn't sure if the file structure was best left as close to the skeleton as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to put doctrine types into `src/Types` (yeah, new folder*) and unless you're importing `UTCDateTimeType` from a library, I would change the namespace to be in line with convention (namespace would be `App\Types` and FQCN `App\Types\UTCDateTimeType`).

**Adding** the type to doctrine is somewhat easy, if you know where - config/packages/doctrine.yaml - this *probably* requires setting the typename via `getName` as seen in here https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            #nameOfType: fullyQualifiedClassName
            utcdatetime: App\Types\UTCDateTimeType
```

(this probably works if you set the name of your type to datetime and datetimetz, my short incomplete tests suggest so...)

however, the tutorial you linked said it wants to **override** the type. I don't know how to achieve this with config (if it's even possible - maybe you ), but you always have the chance to add the noted lines to your `Kernel::configureContainer` or even further up the line in your `public/index.php`.

*folders aren't magical. the existing ones are just the most common ones that are almost always used. adding new ones isn't unusual, so feel free to add them.